# how to insert razor dropdown list in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2010, razor

```
@if (ViewBag.ReportType == "TESTING")
         {   
             <tr id="row_test">
             <td>ZONE :</td><td> @Html.DropDownList("zone", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.zone, new { style = "width:350px"})</td>
             <td>STATE :</td><td> @Html.DropDownList("state", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.state, new { style = "width:350px"})</td>
             <td>COUNTRY:</td><td> @Html.DropDownList("country", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, new { style = "width:350px"})</td>
             </tr>
         }
```

This is the razor code I would like to enter in here

```
$("#reportType").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "TESTING") {
                var testRow = $("#reportType").append($('#row_test').clone()); //this part here is the problem, its not working
                $(testRow).insertAfter("#filter_section");
                $("#zone").focus();
                $("#state").focus();
                $("#country").focus();
            } else {
                $("#row_test").remove();
            }
        });
```

why is this not working? the row is supposed to appear if the value clicked by the user is TESTING. however it does not appear.

#Edit 1: adding reportType for further clarification

```
<div style="height:850px">
<section class="container">
    <table style="width:850px;">
        <tr id="filter_section">
            @*<td style="width:185px;"></td> *@
            <td style="width:120px">REPORT :</td> 
            <td> @Html.DropDownList("reportType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ReportType, new { style = "width:350px" })</td>
            @*<td style="width:185px;"></td> *@
         </tr>
```

The purpose of the report type is to when the user clicks the dropdown list of the report type and clicks TESTING, three more dropdown lists is supposed to appear that is of zone, state and country

Comment: Did you debug the code? Do you see any error in the browser console?

Comment: No there was no error

Comment: I test with `document.getElementById("reportType").innerHTML`,and the html code is added to `reportType`.What you want to get?Why you need to add `<tr></tr>` to dropdown?Can you share your `reportType` and `filter_section`?

Comment: alright shared, and I explained abit of what I wanted to do

Comment: `appear that is of zone, state and country`,you js looks like you want to add the three dropdowns into the `reportType`dropdown?I think you should add the dropdowns to other place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually much simpler with less code, the show and hide function was the one that made it work, attached below:

```
 $("#reportType").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "TESTING") {
                $('#row_test').show();
            } else {
                $("#row_test").hide();
            }
        });
```